# React Material-UI override popover completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I currently using a `Select` component in my app.

[image: select component]

I built a custom modal component that I want to launch **instead of the list items** when the select is clicked. Is there a way to override the handler for clicks on all portions of the component, such as icon, text field, and dropdown arrow to launch my modal? I want to take just the styling of this component essentially and override the `onChange` and `MenuItem` stuff.

```
<Select
  value={props.selectedValue}
  onChange={props.onTimeChange}
  displayEmpty
  startAdornment={
    <InputAdornment position="start">
      <DateRangeIcon />
    </InputAdornment>
  }
>
  {/* DONT USE THESE MENU ITEMS AND USE CUSTOM MODAL INSTEAD */}
  {/*<MenuItem value={-1} disabled>*/}
  {/*  Start Date*/}
  {/*</MenuItem>*/}
  {/*<MenuItem value={1}>Last Hour</MenuItem>*/}
  {/*<MenuItem value={24}>Last Day</MenuItem>*/}
  {/*<MenuItem value={24 * 7}>Last Week</MenuItem>*/}
  {/*<MenuItem value={24 * 31}>Last Month</MenuItem>*/}
  {/*<MenuItem value={''}>All</MenuItem>*/}
</Select>
```

Comment: You can wrap the Select in an outer component like div which has an onClick function that opens up the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for it to make sense to leverage `Select` while using an alternative display for the options, it is important that you provide it with menu items for all the allowed values, because the display of the selected item is based on finding a matching `MenuItem` for the current value (though it would also be possible to provide the `Select` with a single `MenuItem` with a dynamic value and text matching whatever the current selected value is).

You can use a "controlled" approach for managing the `open` state of the `Select` using the `open` and `onOpen` props (you can leave out `onClose` since the close should always be triggered by your custom display of the options). This way, rather than trying to override the different events that cause the `Select` to open, you just let it tell you when it should open (via the `onOpen` prop), but instead of opening the `Select`, leave its `open` prop as always `false` and only open your custom popup.

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import DateRangeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const selectRef = React.useRef();

  const handleSelection = newValue => {
    setValue(newValue);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box m={2}>
      <Select
        ref={selectRef}
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        displayEmpty
        open={false}
        onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
        startAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <DateRangeIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      >
        <MenuItem value={1}>Last Hour</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={24}>Last Day</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={24 * 7}>Last Week</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={24 * 31}>Last Month</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={""}>All</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      <Popover
        id="simple-popover"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={selectRef.current}
        onClose={() => handleSelection(value)}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <Button onClick={() => handleSelection(1)}>Last Hour</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => handleSelection(24)}>Last Day</Button>
      </Popover>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit alternate view of options for Select]

Here's a second example using a single, dynamic MenuItem for the selected value instead of a comprehensive set of menu items:

```
import React from "react";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import DateRangeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("Last Hour");
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const selectRef = React.useRef();

  const handleSelection = (newValue, newText) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    setText(newText);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box m={2}>
      <Select
        ref={selectRef}
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        displayEmpty
        open={false}
        onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
        startAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <DateRangeIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      >
        <MenuItem value={value}>{text}</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      <Popover
        id="simple-popover"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={selectRef.current}
        onClose={() => handleSelection(value)}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <Button onClick={() => handleSelection(1, "Last Hour")}>
          Last Hour
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => handleSelection(24, "Last Day")}>
          Last Day
        </Button>
      </Popover>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit alternate view of options for Select]

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. Using a button is pretty easy since it has the `onClick` prop. I want to have similar behavior with the `Select` component.

Comment: @mvd I've reworked my answer to be something that I think is more what you are looking for. As long as your custom display is limited to the same values as provided by the menu items, I could see how this could still make sense to use `Select`.